# VLC Style does not apply to uninstaller header - Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using a VLC style for my Inno Setup. Everything is fine. The style will apply all over the setup pages and controls. But it will not apply to uninstaller header.
Where is the problem? how to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: This looks like VCL Styles bug (which is not part of Inno Setup but 3rd party tool). I found only really old version from 2013. Maybe it was fixed in newer version. If not then please create new issue here: https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils/issues